# RDS and blazeds have a error in flash builder 4.5 

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, rds

Please help me,
i have a problem about RDS and blazeds, when i use flash builder 4.5 to connect the server data, there is a rds error (403 or 404),but i can ping the "http://10.25.129.151:8400/testdrive/test/" on Chrome or ie. So i don't know how to configure the rds in flash builder 4.5 or i will must configure others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a 403 then the authorization information is incorrect (username and password).

If you're getting a 404 then the address you've specified is invalid.

Double check both and report back to let us know sir, so the next user that hit this can benefit from the question/answer.   :D

Comment: yes, i found it, the problem is the url : "server location: Root url: 'http://localhost:8400/test' " the right url is :"server location: Root url: 'http://10.25.129.151:8400/test' " 
the "localhost is wrong " i think it is our company's policy...
And check the 404 error is: web.xml error,

According to the : 'http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder_blazeds.html'
'https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=lc_blazeds'

Comment: Cool, glad you got it hooked up - happy coding! Thanks for the accept.    :)